# How to get home server to display content from home network externally?

Tags: html, apache, ubuntu

I've set up a home server with Apache Web Server on Ubuntu 16.04. I'm able to see my website externally. But I'm unable to display a video stream that's on my local network on the website.

How would I configure Apache to recognize http://192.168.1.215:8081 and allow it to be shown externally?

Comment: Off topic for StackOverflow: this isn't programming-related. Maybe consider SuperUser? (though it might be off-topic there too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a programming question, but you would need to setup a forward in your router.

Answer (score 0):

If your IP Address allocated by ISP can be accessed on the Internet(*NOT* behind a NAT):

1. Setup port-forwarding on your router
2. (optional) Use an available port. (if some are filtered or blocked by ISP)
3. (optional) Use DDNS if your address is not fixed like a regular server.

If not:

You must have a server as "Springboard" which can be accessed on Internet, then `SSH -R` can be used for forwarding a local port behind NAT to remote.